Why are my leaflet points stuck to the map edge?
I try to plot transit stops on a leaflet map, indicating local clustering ("LISA"), based on Moran's I. The map is embedded in an R markdown file.
I've successfully done that with polygon data, as inspired by this example.
However, when adapting the code to point, the result looks like this:

I've already tried to adjust the CRS, using EPSG:

3857, which seems to be the leaflet standard
4326, another standard
25832, which applies to the area in question (Northern Germany)

stops is my list of transit stops i.e. an sf object of ~7.5k points
I want to analyse autocorrelation of the t2 column. My identifier column is h_id_varchar, I use it to assign the labels.
Any suggestions?
The code:
# set CRS
stops <- st_set_crs(stops, 4326)

# create local weights matrix
  nb_loc <- rgeoda::queen_weights(stops)

# Calculate local Moran's I (t2 is the variable I want to investigate)
moran_loc <- rgeoda::local_moran(nb_loc, stops["t2"])

# define labels and colors by the LISA cluster categories
moran_loc_lbls <- lisa_labels(moran_loc)
moran_loc_colors <- setNames(lisa_colors(moran_loc), moran_loc_lbls)

# Define clusters
moran_clustered <- stops %>%
  mutate(cluster_num = lisa_clusters(moran_loc) + 1,  # add 1 bc clusters are zero-indexed
         cluster = factor(moran_loc_lbls[cluster_num], levels = moran_loc_lbls),
         h_id_varchar = as.character(h_id_varchar))  # Ensure that h_id_varchar is character type

# define color palette
pal <- colorFactor(moran_loc_colors, domain = moran_clustered$cluster)


# define LISA label for each location, based on numeric cluster field
moran_clustered <- mutate(moran_clustered, cluster_label = case_when(
  cluster_num == 1 ~ "No significant clustering",
  cluster_num == 2 ~ "<strong>High t2</strong> in this area, <strong>high t2</strong> in the   neighbouring areas",
  cluster_num == 3 ~ "<strong>Low t2</strong> in this area, <strong>low t2</strong> in the neighbouring areas",
  cluster_num == 4 ~ "<strong>Low t2</strong> in this area, <strong>high t2</strong> in the neighbouring areas",
  cluster_num == 5 ~ "<strong>High t2</strong> in this area, <strong>low t2</strong> in the neighbouring areas",
  cluster_num == 7 ~ "<strong>Isolated:</strong>This area has no neighbours",
  TRUE ~ as.character(cluster_num)  # Default label for other cases

))

# assign labels
moran_clustered$label <- paste0(
  "<strong>",
  moran_clustered$h_id_varchar, "<br/>",
  moran_clustered$h_name, "</strong><br/>",
  moran_clustered$cluster_label
) %>%
  lapply(htmltools::HTML)


# render map
leaflet(moran_clustered) %>%
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB.DarkMatter') %>%
  clearShapes() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    stroke = TRUE,
    fillColor = ~pal(cluster),
    color = "grey30",
    weight = 1,
    fillOpacity = 1,
    radius = 6,  # Adjust the radius size as needed
    label = ~label,
    layerId = ~h_id_varchar
  ) %>%
  addLegend(position = 'bottomright', pal = pal,
            values = moran_clustered$cluster, title = 'LISA Clusters')


EDIT:
ggplot2 plots my points in 3857 without further ado:
stops <- st_as_sf(ausw_input, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 3857)

ggplot(data = stops) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_minimal()



It seems inconsistent CRS between points the tiles (map) and what leaflet think expect. (and to me, there are 2 such inconsistencies, so 3 different interpretation of coordinates)

In your first line, try using st_transform to project stops into the crs you want - at the moment I think st_set_crs might be just setting it without actually reprojecting the coordinates to match.

@AndrewGustar I've spent hours trying several combinations of
stops <- st_transform(stops, crs = st_crs(3857))
and
stops <- st_set_crs(stops, 3857)
and
st_crs(stops) <- 3857.
None of them led to the desired leaflet map. ggplot2 easily plots my points (see my edit above), but I'd like to have a map that I can pan and click, just as I could do with polygons for the same area, Wild guess: There's a broken geometry involved? Any hint to check that?

@GiacomoCatenazzi I narrowed down my example to one set of points, so there can only be one mismatch. I set CRS = 3857 for the points and also included the CRS into the leaflet call: leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.CRS.EPSG3857")))  Would you know of any other option to specify CRS for the tiles?

Tiles: it depends on the source (URL). The tiles names (and location) depends on crs. It is not common not to have a different (so non "WebMecator"). But some publisher may prefer WGS84

Just to try to narrow down where the error is happening, can you get ggplot to plot moran_clustered with geom_sf as expected? If that works, try a simple leaflet plot with the default options for addTiles and addMarkers? Failing that, it is hard to help further unless you share a sample of your data.
